# How to print a range with decimal points in Python?

Tags: python, range

I can print a range of numbers easily using range, but is is possible to print a range with 1 decimal place from -10 to 10?

e.g

`-10.0, -9.9, -9.8` all they way through to +10?

Answer (score 7):

```
[i/10.0 for i in range(-100,101)]
```

(The `.0` is not needed in Python 3.x)

Comment: Note that the `.` is very important. In Python 2 without `from __future__ import division`, this is necessary not to be performing floor division.

Comment: Better yet, do ".0," as that makes it much more obvious then a single decimal point :)

Answer (score 2):

There's [a recipe on ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66472-frange-a-range-function-with-float-increments/) that implements a floating-point range. In your example, you can use it like

```
frange(-10, 10.01, 0.1)
```

Note that this won't generate 1 decimal place on most architectures because of the [floating-point representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). If you want to be exact, use the [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.arange` might serve your purpose well.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea unless you don't use numpy heavily. If it's just for OP's purpose it might be overdoing.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(', '.join('%.1f' % x/10.0 for x in range(-100, 101)))
```

should do exactly what you ask (the printing part, that is!) in any level of Python (a pretty long line of course -- a few hundred characters!-).  You could omit the outer parenthese in Python 2, could omit the `.0` bit in Python 3, etc, but coding as shown will work across Python releases.

Answer (score 0):

Define a simple function, like:

```
def frange(fmin, fmax, fleap):
    cur=fmin
    while cur<fmax:
        yield cur
        cur+=fleap
```

Call it using `generators`, e.g.:

```
my_float_range=[i for i in frange(-10,10,.1)]
```

Some sanity checks (for example, that `fmin<fmax`) can be added to the function body.